# Listeners and their objects

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtextfield, documentlistener

I have a JTextField with a listener for a change-text event.

Can I use this listener to affect the same object it is listening to? For instance, if it detects a "problematic" change, it should delete all the text in that same JTextField object.

Is this possible? It doesn't seem to work...

An example is as follows:
.

```
this.txtSearch.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    validate();
}

public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    validate();
}

public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
    validate();
}

private void validate(){
    if not_good(txtSearch.getText()) {
        txtSearch.setText("");
    }
}
```

Comment: *"It doesn't seem to work..."*  Maybe it is has the day off.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: This use-case might need a [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html).  See [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for details.

Comment: *"For instance, if it detects a "problematic" change, it should delete all the text in that same JTextField object."* So.. if I've typed 55 characters correctly but the 56th is invalid, I lose the 55 correct characters?  That is *harsh.*

Comment: @Andrew: The point is: is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 2):

Changing text in `JTextField` from a `textChanged` event is likely to cause a (possibly infinite) loop of `textChanged` events. Do not do that.

If you want to validate input to a `JTextField` rather use [`InputVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html).

The javadoc contains [some examples of how to use it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html), have a look.

Answer (score 1):

- for `JTextComponent` you have to use proper methods that have got access to the its `Model`
- `Document` is `Model` for `JTextComponent`

for output from keyboard you have got two choices

- for output from `JTextComponent` to outside (to another element(s) in the Swing GUI) use `DocumentListener`
- for `changes` / `filtering` / `modify` inside `JTextComponent` to use `DocumentFilter`